# Finding the argument of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

So I have the following complex number: $z = -2 + 4i$ and I'm trying to find the argument where $\theta$ is between $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$, which I've been told would be $\arctan(\frac{b}{a})$ yet when I do just that, I get  $\arctan(\frac{4}{-2})$. The answer to that question is $-\arctan(\pi + 2)$ which I don't quite understand. I would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: No, the answer is not $-\arctan(\pi+2)$ but I am not sure that you copied that faithfully.

Comment: By the way, there are few options for $\theta$ if $\pi\le\theta\le\pi$. :)

Comment: Hm, I guess they put up the wrong answer then.  Is my answer of $arctan(\frac{-4}{2})$ correct? @YvesDaoust

Comment: Is that in the requested range ?

Comment: It is right? Since it evaluates to somewhere around  $-1$ which is $\geq -\pi$@YvesDaoust

Comment: @ryang: are you sure about your correction ? Because that does not match the official answer (assuming $\pi-\arctan2$).

Comment: @RyanG: I know, but I am trying to restore this $-\arctan(\pi+2)$ to something that makes sense and explain why they added $\pi$.

Comment: His range correction is correct @YvesDaoust

Comment: @RyanG: any idea why $\pi$ ?

Comment: @RyanG: no, I believe that the OP just misplaced $\pi$, but the $\pi$ was there. IMO.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, that's what I said: the OP had likely merely miscopied (π−arctan2) as −arctan(π+2)

Comment: @RyanG: this is not logical.

Comment: No @RyanG that is not correct, it is indeed $-arctan(\pi + 2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $\arg(a+bi)=\arctan(b/a)$ only works if $b>0$. You can avoid using formulae entirely by constructing a a right-angled triangle that has vertices at $A(0,0)$, $B(-2,0)$, and $C(-2,4)$. Then, find the acute angle at $A(0,0)$, and subtract this angle from $\pi$ to find the obtuse angle made with the positive real axis. This will give you the principal argument of $-2+4i$.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear to me!

Comment: @JakeDrone: I'm glad to hear that I could help. Note that it *is* possible to use a formula (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)), but this seems much more convoluted than just thinking about the problem graphically.